# Oracle / SQL Counting Different values from one Column and storing it in a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I really need to know if i can somehow count 4 different values in a column and store it in 4 different variables. Those variables will be used later in that procedure.

This is the code I have but i don't want to use the select statement 4 times but prefferably 1 time.
Is there any way to solve it?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FCountPrizes (dData IN DATE) 
IS 
szostki NUMBER; 
piatki NUMBER; 
czworki NUMBER; 
trojki NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
SELECT COUNT(*) into szostki FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania AND FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) = 6; 
SELECT COUNT(*) into piatki FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania AND FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) = 5; 
SELECT COUNT(*) into czworki FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania AND FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) = 4; 
SELECT COUNT(*) into trojki FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania AND FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) = 3; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(case FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) when 6 then 1 else 0 end), 
       sum(case FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) when 5 then 1 else 0 end),   
       sum(case FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) when 4 then 1 else 0 end),   
       sum(case FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) when 3 then 1 else 0 end)
into szostki, piatki, czworki, trojki 
FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania;
```

According to the comments, wrap each sum with nvl:

```
NVL(sum(case FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) 
        when 3 then 1 else 0 end), 
    0)
```

if you don't expect NULLs in your local variables.

Another option:

```
SELECT max(case func_res when 6 then n else null end), 
       max(case func_res when 5 then n else null end),   
       max(case func_res when 4 then n else null end),   
       max(case func_res when 3 then n else null end)
       into szostki, piatki, czworki, trojki 
FROM (
    SELECT FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) as func_res, count(*) as n
    FROM Losy WHERE dData=DataLosowania
    GROUP BY FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze)
);
```

Comment: I did upvote the answer, but technically there is a difference.  If there are no matches to `data`, then this will the resulting values are `NULL` with this query, but 0 with the original one.

Comment: It works that's why I marked it as best answer but I'm still not sure if it works as i want. It seems to me that FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) is executed 4 times in one record and this function is really complex which slows down entire procedure. I was seeking an option to execute it one time and count 4 types of results.

Comment: @user3079680 I've updated my answer, but I think Oracle is smart enough to calculate the function only once in the select list

Comment: THANKS!! Oracle wasn't smart enough though. Now with 100k records it executes 11 seconds not 43.

Comment: @user3079680 That's interesting. Thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FCountPrizes (dData IN DATE) 
IS
SELECT COUNT(DECODE(CountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze),6,1)) ,
       COUNT(DECODE(CountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze),5,1)) ,
       COUNT(DECODE(CountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze),4,1)) ,
       COUNT(DECODE(CountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze),3,1))
INTO   
       szostki,
       piatki,
       czworki,
       trojki
FROM Losy
 WHERE dData=DataLosowania 
END FCountPrizes;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your data.

```
SELECT FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) value, COUNT(*) records
FROM Losy 
WHERE dData=DataLosowania 
AND FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) in (3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze);
```

You can run it once and do something with the results.  You have choices.

Answer (score 0):

The `PIVOT` version of the query would look something like this:

```
select * from (
  select FCountGuessed(dData, LiczbyMniejsze, LiczbyWieksze) f
  from Losy
  where dData=DataLosowania
)
pivot (
  count(*) for (f) in (
    6 as szostki,
    5 as piatki,
    4 as czworki,
    3 as trojki
  )
)
```